# Difference of the absolute Value of two (dependent?) random variables

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

Disclosure: this is part of an exam I failed if thats against the rules please let me know I will delete my question. I want to prepare for the next iteration of the exam but I can't figure out how to do this exercise even now that I have the time to research.

The first part of the exercise was to set up the joint distribution $f_{x,y} = f_x \cdot f_{y|x} = \frac{1}{5x}$ and integrating out $x$.

$f_{y|x}(y|x)= \frac{1}{x}, \text{ if 0 < y < x}$

$ f_x(x)=
 \begin{cases}
   \frac{1}{5},&\text{if 3 < x <8}\\
  0,&\text{o.w.}\\
 \end{cases}$

After doing this (hopefully right) we now have the marginal pdfs of the random variable $Y$:

$ f_y(y)=
 \begin{cases}
   \frac{1}{5} log(\frac{8}{3})  ,&\text{if 0 < y <3}\\
         \frac{1}{5} log(\frac{8}{y})  ,&\text{if 3 < y <8}\\ 
  0,&\text{o.w.}\\
 \end{cases}$

In the second part we had to find:

$P(|X-Y|<1)$

Here is where I am totally stuck. I know that I could use the convolution formula to get to the pdf of $Z=X-Y$ and then I could shmabey get to $F(|Z|)$ but I am really stuck here since the formula only works for independent variables as far as I know.

Comment: hint: $f_{x-y}(d) = \int f_x(x) f_{y|x}(x-d) dx$

Comment: Do you need further explanations?

Comment: No your posting was very helpful! Thank you a lot! I did not reply to your posting because Stack Exchange states that one should not say thanks for replies/answers. But rest assured you solved a big mystery for me! I might need help with another exercise tho :D

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to calculate pdf of $Z$ to find $\mathbb P(|X-Y|<1)$. Look at the blue area on the picture

[image: area 3<x<8 and 0<x-y<1 is colored]

You should integrate joint pdf within this area:
$$
\mathbb P(|X-Y|<1) = \mathbb P(0<X-Y<1) = \int\limits_3^8 \int\limits_{x-1}^x \frac{1}{5x}\, dy\, dx.
$$